# Problema com identificação 'target'

Tags: javascript

Estrutura do Progama:

```
<body>

    <div class = 'tabuleiro' onclick = 'clicar()'>
        <div id = 'a1' class = 'espaco'></div>
        <div id = 'a2' class = 'espaco'></div>
        <div id = 'a3' class = 'espaco'></div>

        <div id = 'b1' class = 'espaco'></div>
        <div id = 'b2' class = 'espaco'></div>
        <div id = 'b3' class = 'espaco'></div>

        <div id = 'c1' class = 'espaco'></div>
        <div id = 'c2' class = 'espaco'></div>
        <div id = 'c3' class = 'espaco'></div>
    </div>
    <input type="button" value="clicar" onclick = 'resultado()'>

<script>
    var a1 = document.getElementById('a1').innerHTML
    var a2 = document.getElementById('a2').innerHTML
    var a3 = document.getElementById('a3').innerHTML

    var b1 = document.getElementById('b1').innerHTML
    var b2 = document.getElementById('b2').innerHTML
    var b3 = document.getElementById('b3').innerHTML

    var c1 = document.getElementById('c1').innerHTML
    var c2 = document.getElementById('c2').innerHTML
    var c3 = document.getElementById('c3').innerHTML

    var vitoria = false

    function clicar(){
        var espaco_selecionado = event.target
        espaco_selecionado.innerHTML = 'X'
    }

    function conferir(){                                //*DÚVIDA
        if (a1 == 'X' && a2 == 'X' && a3 == 'X'){
            window.alert('VITORIA')
        }
    }
    
</script>
</body>
```

O problema é que o programa não identifica que as variáveis a1, a2 e a3, estão com o valor 'X', mesmo eu tendo uma função (clicar()) que coloca tal valor nelas.

Comment: você quer comparar o html ( conteudo do id ) com as variaveis ?

Comment: O texto do html é copiado somente e não tem referencia do texto.
Exemplo: `var t = 2; var c = t; t = 4;` Output: `t=4,c=2`

Comment: Importante você [edit] sua pergunta e explicar de maneira objetiva e pontual a dificuldade encontrada, acompanhada de um [mcve] do problema e tentativa de solução. Para aproveitar melhor o site, entender e evitar fechamentos e negativações vale a pena ler o [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/70).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lembre-se de que o navegador irá interpretar seu script uma única vez. Então quando o navegador passa pela linha
`var a1 = document.getElementById('a1').innerHTML`, o valor de `a1` é vazio. Este valor vazio é atribuido á variável `a1`. Quando o `innerHTML` é alterado no clique do mouse, você não está atualizando o valor do `a1`, portanto sua lógica dentro da função `conferir` não funciona da forma esperada.

A alteração abaixo deve te ajudar a resolver o problema:

```js
  var a1 = document.getElementById('a1');
  var a2 = document.getElementById('a2');
  var a3 = document.getElementById('a3');

  var b1 = document.getElementById('b1');
  var b2 = document.getElementById('b2');
  var b3 = document.getElementById('b3');

  var c1 = document.getElementById('c1');
  var c2 = document.getElementById('c2');
  var c3 = document.getElementById('c3');

  var vitoria = false

  function clicar(){
      var espaco_selecionado = event.target
      espaco_selecionado.innerHTML = 'X'
  }

  function conferir(){                                //*DÚVIDA
      if (a1.innerHTML == 'X' && a2.innerHTML == 'X' && a3.innerHTML == 'X') {
          window.alert('VITORIA')
      }
  }
```

```css
.tabuleiro {
    background: #efefef;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.espaco {
    background: #ccc;
    height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 30%;
}
```

```html
<div class="tabuleiro" onclick="clicar()">
    <div id="a1" class="espaco"></div>
    <div id="a2" class="espaco"></div>
    <div id="a3" class="espaco"></div>

    <div id="b1" class="espaco"></div>
    <div id="b2" class="espaco"></div>
    <div id="b3" class="espaco"></div>

    <div id="c1" class="espaco"></div>
    <div id="c2" class="espaco"></div>
    <div id="c3" class="espaco"></div>
</div>
<input type="button" value="clicar" onclick="conferir()">
```

Answer (score 0):

Boa noite Davi Ribeiro,

Só no seu código só está faltando você passar o evento como parametro na função.
tente isso:

```
<body>

    <div class = 'tabuleiro' onclick = 'clicar(event)'>
        <div id = 'a1' class = 'espaco'></div>
        <div id = 'a2' class = 'espaco'></div>
        <div id = 'a3' class = 'espaco'></div>

        <div id = 'b1' class = 'espaco'></div>
        <div id = 'b2' class = 'espaco'></div>
        <div id = 'b3' class = 'espaco'></div>

        <div id = 'c1' class = 'espaco'></div>
        <div id = 'c2' class = 'espaco'></div>
        <div id = 'c3' class = 'espaco'></div>
    </div>
    <input type="button" value="clicar" onclick = 'resultado()'>

<script>
    var a1 = document.getElementById('a1').innerHTML
    var a2 = document.getElementById('a2').innerHTML
    var a3 = document.getElementById('a3').innerHTML

    var b1 = document.getElementById('b1').innerHTML
    var b2 = document.getElementById('b2').innerHTML
    var b3 = document.getElementById('b3').innerHTML

    var c1 = document.getElementById('c1').innerHTML
    var c2 = document.getElementById('c2').innerHTML
    var c3 = document.getElementById('c3').innerHTML

    var vitoria = false

    function clicar(event){
        var espaco_selecionado = event.target
        espaco_selecionado.innerHTML = 'X'
    }

    function conferir(){                                //*DÚVIDA
        if (a1 == 'X' && a2 == 'X' && a3 == 'X'){
            window.alert('VITORIA')
        }
    }
    
</script>
</body>
```

No entanto no seu código tem um botão "clicar" que chama uma função "resultado()" que não existe no javascript acima, então esse pode ser o seu problema também, mas a principio o erro que você relatou se deve ao fato de estar chamando target do event que não estava vindo na função.

Espero ter ajudado!

Answer (score 0):

Os dados do tipo string não recebe referência de um valor, mas sim somente uma cópia que foi recebida.

Exemplo:

```js
var t = "2";
var c = t;
t = "3"
console.log(`t: ${t},c: ${c}`)
```

Alguns tipos de dados tem referência como por exemplo: Objeto e Function

```js
var t = {}
var c = t
t.d = 2;
console.log(t)
console.log(c)
```

Solução do problema é referência por meio de uma function o texto.

Exemplo:

```js
// Referenciado a propriedade document.getElementById("test").innerHTML
var test_text = () => document.getElementById("test").innerHTML;

console.log(test_text())

document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "Hello World2!"

console.log(test_text())
```

```html
<html>
<p id="test">Hello World!</p>
</html>
```

Eu espero que tenha ajudado.